# Custom text in tooltip and legend: ChartJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, chart.js

Im using Doughnut chartjs. The tooltip text is too long that is gets cut. So i wanted to add ellipsis(...) at the end of the tooltip text. But ellipsis gets added in legend also. How do add different text in legend and tooltip?

**controller.js**

```
doughnutData.push({
'value': value.count, color: $scope.doughNutColors[key],
highlight: $scope.doughNutColors[key], label: value.website
});
```

**directive.js**

```
$scope.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(value, {
                    showScale: true, scaleShowLabels: true, animation: false,
                    tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>:<%=value%>%<%}%>",
                    legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"doughnutalt-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"border-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><label><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></label></li><%}%></ul>",
});
```

Comment: I want different text in legend and tooltip

Comment: Can you please add a fiddle.

Comment: Check this out it might help ----------> http://jsfiddle.net/7ff9k9cd/1/ <------------

Comment: thanks @Help. I did a code by myself like the one in fiddle and its fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it

```
{
...
tooltipTemplate: function (label) {
                        return customTooltip(label);
                    }

});

function customTooltip (label) {
                    if (label.label.length > 10) {
                        label.label = label.label.substring(0,10)+'...';
                    }
                    return label.label+': '+label.value+'%';
}
```

Don't know if this is the right code. But it did what i wanted